# Flickr API not returning correct photos when searching by tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, flickr

I have a ruby on rails app that is using the Gem flickraw to query the Flickr API.
I am using flickr.photos.search passing in one tag as well as asking to return the "extras" owner_name,date_taken,and geo as described here:
https://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.photos.search.htm

When I hard code my user_id it returns my photos that are tagged with the tag i am searching for. When i hard code my friends user_id it returns his images that are tag with the same tag.

When i remove user_id altogether it returns 3 images that are all over 2 years old but not our images.
Why aren't our images returned?
We have checked the privacy settings and all our photos are available publicly. the "block search" option is off.

We added and tagged the photos over 2 weeks ago and they are not showing up, does Flickr take over two weeks to index their photos?

```
  class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

  def get_flickr_list
    require 'flickraw'
    FlickRaw.api_key="API_KEY_GOES_HERE"
    FlickRaw.shared_secret="SECRET_GOES_HERE"

    list = flickr.photos.search user_id: "USER_ID_HERE (unless removed entirely)",
                                tags: "opentree",
                                extras: "owner_name,date_taken,geo"
    return list
  end
```

Comment: so now, my fiends photos are showing up. seems it just takes three weeks to index the photos! mine were added a few days after his so i will see if mine show up soon too.

Comment: my photo is still not indexed and showing? anybody have any thoughts?